Aristotelian Syllogisms: Validity by reduction via reductio ad impossibile?
I'm trying to learn Aristotle's Organon but am finding Chapter 7 (volume I) of Prior Analytics difficult to comprehend, i.e., providing validity indirect (reductio ad impossibile) reduction.
Indirect Reduction
The process seems to be:

Find contradiction of a syllogism's conclusion
Use contradiction of conclusion as minor premise with original syllogism's major premise
Check to see if result contradicts original syllogism's minor premise (contradiction: Valid, no contradiction: invalid)

For example, with a valid (AOO-2) Syllogism:



AOO-2 (Valid)
Major Premise and Contradictory
Result




All N are M
All N are M
Some O is not M


Some O are not M
All O are N
Contradicted by


Therefore, Some O are not N
Therefore, All O are M
All O are M



There's a clear contradiction in this case (and a perfect AAA-1 syllogism), So AOO-2 seems to be proven valid. However, I'm not sure about contrary results (although both can't be true, so should still count?), e.g., with another valid (EAO-3) syllogism:



EAO-3 (Valid)
Major Premise and Contradictory
Result




No S are P
No S are P
No R are S / No S are R


All S are R
All R are P
Contrary to


Therefore, Some R are not P
Therefore, No R are S
All S are R



Is this contrary still a proof of validity?
Finally, it seems invalid syllogisms tested this way results in invalid reductions with logically undetermined conclusions, e.g. AEE-1:



AEE-1 (Invalid)
Major Premise and Contradictory
Result




All B are A
All B are A
No C are B


No C are B
Some C are A
Not Contradicted by


Therefore, No C are A
Therefore, Some C are B (invalid)
Invalid conclusion



So, although the conclusion of the Major Premise and Contradictory seems to contradict the minor premise of the original syllogism, as the conclusion is invalid, there is no contradiction, thus providing AEE-1 to be invalid.
Is this how reductio ad impossibile works? Much thanks!

Aristotle distinguishes perfect from imperfect deductions, where the latter are perfected by reduction to a perfect form. In each case the proof is direct or 'through the impossible' which we might understand as a proof by contradiction. There is some useful material in the SEP article on Aristotelian logic.
